# Internet error hanging on TLS handshake and TB at connected to pop3

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, tls, motherboard

Since yesterday I have a problem with my wired internet connection only on Ubuntu, Win7 works fine (dual boot), Thunderbird hangs at `connected to pop3` and receives no e-mails and various websites hang at TLS handshake.: duckduckgo, ustart.org though google is there in a second.

I have already tried

- renaming cert8.db
- `sudo nano /etc/gai.conf`
- `locate #precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` and remove the #.
- reboot
- Disconnect from Internet with 
  `sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"1"`
  Connect to the Internet again

All without success

I do not know commands by heart but mostly try some sudo commands I find on this forum or online, as I am not an ubuntu adept.
I hope someone can help, I am now on Windows7 :(

Comment: Since I did not find a solution I decided to install Ubuntu again but this resulted in the same problem with TLS handshake and also not being able to connect when I tried to update with terminal (waiting for headers), Software is also giving an error "unable to download firmware updates from "fwupd".So there is a problem with the network, though not on Windows 7, also resetting the modem did not solve it.

Comment: I asked my provider to reboot my modem, something that solved the TLS handshake issue for someone else I read but it also did not help. so I still have this problem in Ubuntu.

Comment: I actually stopped using Ubuntu after using it for 4 years, because of this issue. I hope someone will come with a solution one day.

Answer (score 1):

I am very happy that I found the 'solution' for this problem.
It turns out that the ethernet connector on my motherboard (Foxconn 671-MX)did not work in Ubuntu but it does in Windows. I ordered a new pci ethernetcard today and ethernet works again.
1 year and four months without Ubuntu and many attemps with commands that did not help but back on Ubuntu again :).